# Applying redo entries from one database to the DR databse

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, storage

We have a crisis at the moment. Our production database crashed and we have switched to our backup site. Unfortunately, that DB is 24hrs behind and we know in a financial institution, that's a lot of transactions behind. Am wondering if it's possible to apply redo entries from the production environment to the backup site.

Keep in mind, am only a junior DBA and trying to offer suggestion to my superiors so don't ask if I tried it. I don't call the shots but once I have a concrete plan on how to go about it, I can suggest.

Comment: Could you take a copy of your backup and then _try_ to apply the redo log? I would guess that if it applies cleanly then it would be good to use that as the new live.

Comment: Actually, the EMC storage is where the issue lies. We have several terabytes of data and connecting the applications to the database takes forever and we can't easily replicate that (storage capacity issues and the environment). We have the DR up which is serving as live now but we had to manually re-key every transaction which I believe is inefficient. That's why I asked if it's possible to apply the redo entries in the DR database. Keep in mind, in the heat of the chaos, we could not do try and error.

Comment: If it is of critical importance, can you get an Oracle specialist in, either from Oracle themselves or a good freelancer? It seems rather too critical (and slow) to fish on Stack Overflow for a problem of this kind.

Comment: For the future, can you get your backup to be less than 24 hours behind? It seems like you've uncovered major problem in your DR.

Comment: Sure @halfer. We have uncovered a lot and we actually had an expert flown in to help. Still hoping it comes backup soon.